# create and object with variables and pass it through an other class

Tags: c#

I have tried to explain it as good as i can in the code sample showing, I'm not sure if what I want is possible in one or another way.

the folowing code does work but I cant pass a `null` value and I'm not able to change the value in the 'object' after i created it.
How can i create a variableTable object that can do this?

```
public static void SomeMethod(string variableOne, int variableTwo, UInt64 variableThree)
    {
        //create an object that contains variables for this specific method
        //there are more methods like this 'SomeMethod' that have diferent variables and more or less variables
        //this 'VariableHandler' reads and modifies the values via reflection and needs to be able to be used on onther methods
        //also the variables can be null and this is not possible with an anonymous types
        var variableTable = new { variableOne = variableOne, variableTwo = variableTwo, variableThree = variableThree }; //create an anomymous type with the variables

        using (VariableHandler handler = new VariableHandler(variableTable)) //check and modify the variables via reflection
        {
            Console.WriteLine(variableTable.variableOne);       //do  somthing with the checked and modified methods
            Console.WriteLine(variableTable.variableTwo);
            Console.WriteLine(variableTable.variableThree);

        }
    }
```

Comment: If an anonymous type is not sufficient then you'll just have to write a class for this. But what exactly are you trying to achieve with this? There might be a better solution if you can give us some more context.

Comment: Maybe you should be using an [`ExpandoObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of an anonymous type.

Comment: @RonBeyer Yeah i tried that, but the problem i ran in to is that i have the disadvantages of a dynamic object, and the code that will not get checked on compile time. and be a pain for other people to use the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use a small object then for each individual variable, like:

```
public interface IVariableValue { }

public class VariableValue<T> : IVariableValue
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public VariableValue(T value) { Value = value; }

    public override ToString() { return Value.ToString(); }
}
```

The interface is required because you need some common type to store in the dictionary. Its a blank interface because I can't define the `T Value` property without also making the interface generic and running into the same problem of having multiple generic types in the same dictionary.

Then, instead of an anonymous type, use a `Dictionary`:

```
public static void SomeMethod(string variableOne, int variableTwo, UInt64 variableThree)
{
    var variableTable = new Dictionary<string, IVariableValue>()
        {
            ["variableOne"] = new VariableValue<string>(variableOne),
            ["variableTwo"] = new VariableValue<int>(variableTwo),
            ["variableThree"] = new VariableValue<UInt64>(variableThree),
        };

    using (VariableHandler handler = new VariableHandler(variableTable))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(variableTable["variableOne"]);
        Console.WriteLine(variableTable["variableTwo"]);
        Console.WriteLine(variableTable["variableThree"]);
    }
}
```

**Note** the dictionary initializer is a C#6 feature, if you aren't on C#6, you'll have to `.Add` to the Dictionary after you create it.

The `VariableHandler` can take a parameter of `Dictionary<string, IVariableValue>` in the constructor:

```
public class VariableHandler : IDisposable
{
    //IDisposable implementation not shown, but required for using

    public VariableHandler(Dictionary<string, IVariableValue> variables)
    {
        //You can do whatever you want here using reflection
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i didnt think about that, this does solve all my problems :)

Answer (score 1):

According to MSDN ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx)), properties on anonymous types are read-only--so of course you can't change them.  It also states you can't initialize the properties to null.

Why this is--you'll have to ask Microsoft, or read the article--there might be more there for you.

If you want to be able to change the properties or initialize them to null, you need to create an object that is not anonymous.

Comment: Yes i know that... that is exacly what i said in my post. and my question is exacly how to create that kind of object.

Comment: Sounds like you need to spend time with a tutorial, such as this: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/classes/introduction/.  Classes are pretty fundamental to C#.

Comment: like i said in my post this code needs to be able to  be implemented in every kind of method with diferent variables, so i can create a class for each method. but that would be realy ineficient so, it would be helpfull if i could do it in this inside the body of the method eleminating the need of creating 100's of classes, and only need to fill in a small line of code like here.

Answer (score 0):

While Ron's answer does what you need, I think it can be solved in a less verbose way.

If argument names are not particularly important, but the ability to pass on arguments as a bundle, to modify them and use them to call a method again, then perhaps a `Tuple`-like class with writable properties is sufficient:

```
public static class Arguments
{
    // This convenience method enables type-inference, so the generic types
    // don't need to be supplied (which is necessary when calling the
    // Arguments<T1, T2, T3> constructor):
    public static Arguments<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
    {
        return new Arguments<T1, T2, T3>(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
}

public class Arguments<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public T1 Argument1 { get; set; }
    public T2 Argument2 { get; set; }
    public T3 Argument3 { get; set; }

    public Arguments(T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
    {
        Argument1 = arg1;
        Argument2 = arg2;
        Argument3 = arg3;
    }
}
```

This can be used as following:

```
public static void SomeMethod(string variableOne, int variableTwo, UInt64 variableThree)
{
    var arguments = Arguments.Create(variableOne, variableTwo, variableThree);

    Console.WriteLine(arguments.Argument1);
    Console.WriteLine(arguments.Argument2);
    Console.WriteLine(arguments.Argument3);
}
```

You do have to create a separate class and convenience method for each *number* of arguments that must be supported, similar to how there are different `Tuple` classes for different numbers of items.

**Parameter names**

If you do need to preserve the parameter names, in such a way that you can write `arguments.variableOne`, without going dynamic, then you'll have to write a class for each method. At that point you may as well modify those methods to accept such an object as a single parameter.

If you need the parameter names at run-time, you can use reflection to get information about the calling method. To do so reliably can be tricky - several methods such as strack-trace inspection or calling `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` will fail in the face of method inlining, as Ron points out.

Passing a reference to the method directly should work, however:

```
public class Arguments
{
    public static Arguments<T1, T2, T3> Create<T1, T2, T3>(Action<T1, T2, T3> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
    {
        return new Arguments<T1, T2, T3>(action, arg1, arg2, arg3);
    }
}

public class Arguments<T1, T2, T3>
{
    public Argument<T1> Argument1 { get; set; }
    public Argument<T2> Argument2 { get; set; }
    public Argument<T3> Argument3 { get; set; }


    public Arguments(Action<T1, T2, T3> action, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3)
    {
        var methodInfo = action.GetMethodInfo();
        var parameters = methodInfo.GetParameters();

        Argument1 = new Argument<T1>(parameters[0].Name, arg1);
        Argument2 = new Argument<T2>(parameters[1].Name, arg2);
        Argument3 = new Argument<T3>(parameters[2].Name, arg3);
    }
}

// A wrapper class to hold both the name and value of a parameter/argument:
public class Argument<T>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public T Value { get; set; }


    public Argument(string name, T value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Usage changes to:

```
public static void SomeMethod(string variableOne, int variableTwo, UInt64 variableThree)
{
    var arguments = Arguments.Create(SomeMethod, variableOne, variableTwo, variableThree).Dump();

    Console.WriteLine(arguments.Argument1.Name + " = " + arguments.Argument1.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(arguments.Argument2.Name + " = " + arguments.Argument2.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(arguments.Argument3.Name + " = " + arguments.Argument3.Value);
}
```

Comment: Your Argument class value requires boxing where the generic type does not. this may also have an issue if called from an inlined method or lambda, but I'd have to test that.

Comment: @RonBeyer: good points. Lambdas work fine, but inlining will mess this up. To prevent that this system would have to accept a `MethodBase` as argument instead of fetching it via stack inspection. Callers would need to pass in `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` and that should be all. As for boxing, if that's a concern then yeah, go generic. The result would probably look a helper method that produces a dictionary or object containing generic argument objects, much like your solution. I'll update this when I have some extra time.

Comment: So `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod()` is not reliable in the face of inlining either. Looks like the most reliable way to get the current method would be to create helper methods that take an `Expression<Action/Func>` argument, but that requires the caller to provide type arguments. That's getting less and less concise. Thinking about it, a `Tuple`-like class with writable properties might just be sufficient for the OP.